# Using Large Lists

Tags: c#, performance, list

In an Outlook AddIn I'm working on, I use a list to grab all the messages in the current folder, then process them, then save them.  First, I create a list of all messages, then I create another list from the list of messages, then finally I create a third list of messages that need to be moved.  Essentially, they are all copies of each other, and I made it this way to organize it.  Would it increase performance if I used only one list? I thought lists were just references to the actual item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without seeing your code it is impossible to tell if you are creating copies of the list itself or copies of the *reference* to the list - the latter is preferable.

Another thing to consider is whether or not you could stream the messages from Outlook using an [iterator block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee5kxzk0%28VS.80%29.aspx).  By using a `List<T>` you are currently buffering the entire sequence of messages which means you must hold them all in memory, processing them one at a time.  Streaming the messages would reduce the memory pressure on your application as you would only need to hold each message in memory long enough to process it.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your lists contains 10 millions items or more, it should not be a problem.

Outlook seems to have a problem much smaller sized mailboxes, so I would say you are pretty much safe.